# How to configure PulseAudio for better sound quality?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, tweak, quality

I want to configure PulseAudio to get better sound quality because right now it's pretty bad.

I saw a tutorial but I can't do it because I don't have so much knowledge of how linux works.

Comment: So what is the reason for not including the link to that tutorial?

Comment: Ah, i don't know. :D didn't think of that. Here it is :  https://medium.com/@gamunu/enable-high-quality-audio-on-linux-6f16f3fe7e1f

Comment: Soooo can anyone help me?

Comment: information in the link is generally correct, but if sound is lacking bass you may only need to adjust lfe-remixing settings. Some of the suggested settings on there do not need to be that high, and will eat into CPU load. you don't need to use all the options suggested, settings options are all commented out in system file and can be uncommented later if wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try pulse EQ, it's by far the easiest method for better audio quality. 
Located in software center, synaptic or on webupd8 website using a ppa.
I found the eq does a great job adding bass to my crappy headphones

Have fun

Comment: I will definitely try it. Thanks for the answer. I was waiting for someone to comment.

Comment: Oh yes definitely better sound. THANK YOU SO MUCH SIR. You saved me. Cheers!

Comment: @Predator1112 If you find this answer useful you [may "accept" it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking on the tick mark (✓) next to it) so others may more easily find it in the future.